# Custom "Previous" & "Next" text in react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

Is there a way to customize the text in the footer part of react-table?

[image: This part of the react-table]

I'm trying to customize the default text there.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per the doc here [react-table](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table#columns), it is possible to add custom Footers to the table using the `Footer` property of the `columns` prop of the component.

*However* , if you want to change the `Previous` and `Next` text as seen in the screenshot i'd say you have to change the `nextText` and `prevText` props of the main `ReactTable` components, more can be seen here [in the props documentation](https://github.com/react-tools/react-table#props)

Comment: Thank you! After checking the docs, I just define the custom text as props, then everything goes fine.

Answer (score 8):

So after checking the docs, what I did is just define the custom text as props of the ReactTable.

```
<ReacTable 
   previousText={myCustomPreviousText}
   nextText={myCustomNextText}
   {...}
/>
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the `previousText` and `nextText` props mentioned in other answers, React Table also supports custom components using the `PreviousComponent` and `NextComponent` props

(from [the docs](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme))